# Loop through a ListBox and set TextBox Text

Tags: c#, loops, timer, listboxitem

How do I auto select a item in a `ListBox` then set it as text in a `TextBox` then wait 3 seconds and move onto the next line down and repeat?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        textBox2.Text = listBox1.Text;                
    }
}
```

Comment: Increment the `SelectedIndex` in `timer1_Tick`. You don't want a loop there, because you want to process only one item at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `timer1_Tick` should be something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Interval = 3000;
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int i = rnd.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count - 1);
    textBox2.Text = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();            
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
int i;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (i > listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        i = 0;//Set this to repeat
        return;
    }
    textBox2.Text = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

And also set the timer's Interval to `3000`.

Comment: this is perfect but how do i make it so its not random ?

Comment: @Waypast...See my edited answer again to see how to repeat the process by setting `i = 0;` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The ListBox has a lot of useful properties:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % listBox1.Items.Count;
}
```

`%` is the modulo operation and returns the remainder of the division. It ensures that always values between `0` and `SelectedIndex - 1` are returned and makes the indexes repeat.

Also, if no item is selected, you will get a `SelectedIndex` of `-1` and `SelectedItem` will be `null`. So be sure to either avoid these cases by setting appropriate initial conditions or add checks.

E.g.:

```
if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0) {
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    ... // code of above
}
```